# Moving rows in a table (SQL/OLEDB) to fill missing IDs and another incremental value

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I'm developing a program that cancels redundant rows in a table with image names. The problem is that if I delete n rows (each image has n rows), I'd have to move the next n rows 1 position down for the image record number and n positions down (incremental) for the ID. I'd like, after I deleted all the records I need to, to put all rows together without leaving any value gap between ID and the other incremental value. Anyone knows how to do? Probably I've explained everything quite bad, so here's an example of how it should look.
Before:

```
ID      recNum          image
1       1       firstImage.png
2       1       firstImage.png
3       1       firstImage.png
4       2       secondImage.png
5       2       secondImage.png
6       2       secondImage.png
7       3       thirdImage.png
8       3       thirdImage.png
9       3       thirdImage.png
```

After deleting "secondImage.png" rows:

```
ID      recNum      image
1       1       firstImage.png
2       1       firstImage.png
3       1       firstImage.png
4       2       thirdImage.png
5       2       thirdImage.png
6       2       thirdImage.png
```

I'm still figuring out how to make that

Comment: You have to remove from end and move toward beginning.  So use for(i = list.Length -1; i >= 0; i-- ) { enter code here to delete item i }

Comment: Can't you use SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Start at the end with the first deletion and then go towards index 0

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in SQL. You're deleting 3 ids and 1 rec num, so you're update statement would be...

```
UPDATE images
SET ID= ID - 3, recNum = recNum - 1
WHERE ID >= 7
```

It's generally not a good idea to change the id of things! These will be referenced elsewhere and usually it's more important to have stable ids, at the price of introducing gaps in the sequence.